# Java Script : Opening a link is userdefind browser

Tags: javascript

I Want to open a link in userdefind browser in javascript. 
For example if i click on a button and I am using chrome , the onclick link should open in firefox .

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @user3219080: You do understand that JavaScript works inside a browser right?

Answer (score 5):

To do this you need to access the user's machine and there are a number of reasons why no browser will allow this. There's no such browser-to-browser communication.

Comment: I have seen some sites that do something like this when you click the link chrome asks you if you want to open the external app

Comment: @Qwertie that's interesting. Can you give an example of such site

Comment: on my site http://triangularcircle.weebly.com/ there is a option to donate bitcoins, clicking it will open the bitcoin app if you have it installed but chrome will ask first. the code looks like this: href="bitcoin:14FiRacgshhj9t6ho2eELaEVaoTAMREDgx" if the app is not installed it will open a empty page with the href in the address bar

Comment: @Qwertie the question mentioned nothing about mobile, I automatically assumed it's regarding desktop usage `:D`

Comment: I was talking about PC

Comment: it seems to work like "href="appname:DataToGiveToApp"

Comment: @Qwertie well I tested that on Win7, didn't seem to work. I think there's an addon that can do that but do you really want to obligate users to install it

Comment: Here I found a reference http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailtov this code opens your email app. it uses the similar code to my website

Comment: But this is html not JS

Answer (score 1):

The subject you're talking about is related to URI scheme (incorrectly referred to as "protocols" or URI protocols or URL protocols). There are many different URI schemes such as http, https, ftp, mailto, javascript, git and so on. There is a list of them in [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml). E.g. the following link uses a mailto URI scheme:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send email</a>
```

It allows users clicking a link in a website to send an e-mail without first having to copy the destination e-mail address and open an e-mail client. Though its use is not strictly defined, URLs of this form are intended to be used to open the new message window of the user's email client when the URL is activated, with the address as defined by the URL in the "To:" field. [wikipedia mailto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)

As long as I know there is a single **http** URI scheme which is associated with a specific application by your browser (itself!) and a specific mail client for mailto URI scheme, and so on. So you can not open an http URI scheme with different applications or you should find different URI scheme which are assigned to different applications in your browser configurations.